# random non repeating array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am trying to build a table with 15 random numbers as part of a project to make the 15 puzzle game in html/javascript. I am going to insert random non-repeating numbers from an array in the first 15 spots of a table. I can't seem to get the alert with the array to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

EDIT: now i am still getting some repeating numbers. i don't understand why since im pretty sure the array is being checked for duplicates.

```
<script>

    var arr = [];
    function roll() {

        for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
            if (arr.indexOf(i) != randomNumber) {
                arr.push(randomNumber);

            }
        } alert("This Works" + arr);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: No need to make function recurisve

Comment: so, you want numbers 1...15 in random order, one of each?? `Array.from({length:15}).map((unused, index) => index + 1).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting duplicates because you are not checking new numbers agains all existing numbers. Hope this helps:

```js
var arr = [];
function roll() {
  var randomNumber;
  do {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    if (!arr.includes(randomNumber)) {
      arr.push(randomNumber);
    }
  } while (arr.length < 15)
  alert("This Works: " + arr);
}
roll();
```

Comment: omg thank you, i swapped out the if statement and put the i++ after the push it is working perfectly. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is because of it went never end loop. You can see the error in your console like `Out of stack space`. You have called the `roll` function on your `if` condition. That `if` condition will never fails as per your calculation using `Math`. Remove method call and try to run, you will get the alert.

```
var arr = [];
function roll() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != randomNumber) {
            arr[arr.length] = randomNumber;               
        }
    } alert("This Works" + arr);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/p4p9j1zt/)

Comment: you should add the demo here itself

Answer (score 0):

Use `arr.indexOf` to check the element is present in array. And don't use recursive function and loop together for a single dimensional array manipulation. Always use `arr.push()` method to insert into an array which is best practice

```js
var arr = [];

function roll() {
  for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    if (arr.indexOf(randomNumber) < 0) {
      arr.push(randomNumber);
    } else i--;
  }
  alert("This Works " + arr);
}
roll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant see alert to work because you are not calling your roll() function anywhere . 
Please see below the code. You have many error in your code as well like the function is `Math.floor`and i is undefined in your code , also remove the function call roll inside roll function as its a never ending loop or you have to put the function call in a condition to make it work.

Please see below the corrected code.

```
<script>

var arr = [];
function roll() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != randomNumber) {
            arr[arr.length] = randomNumber;
        }
    } alert("This Works" + arr);
}
roll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. It should be `Math.floor` instead of `Math.Floor`.

You're not breaking the recursive call anywhere. So it will make a max call stack size exceeded error.

I used `Array#find` instead of traditional `for loop` in the below example.

```js
var arr = [];

function roll() {
  if(arr.length>=15){
    console.log(arr);
    return;
  }
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
  if(arr.find(elm => elm == randomNumber)==undefined){
    arr.push(randomNumber);
   }
   roll();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="roll();">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

//here is the code that may help you to solve the issue

```
    var arr = [];
    function roll() {

        for (; ; ) {
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
            if(arr.indexOf(randomNumber) == -1){
                 arr[arr.length] = randomNumber;
                 if(arr.length == 15)
                    break;
            }
        } 
        alert(arr)
    }
    roll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
var arr = [];

function roll() {
  for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    if (arr.indexOf(randomNumber) < 0) {
      arr[arr.length] = randomNumber;
    }
  }
  alert("This Works " + arr);
}
roll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion):

```
function roll(size, arr) {
    arr = arr || [];
    if(size <= 0) return arr;
    return roll(size-1, arr.concat([Math.ceil(Math.random() * 15)]));
}

console.log("This Works: " + roll(15));
console.log("This Works: " + roll(10, []));
```

`Math.floor(...) + 1` has become `Math.ceil(...)` as both are the same.

Comment: It should check for the existence also to ensure uniqueness.